# Pop up window automatically on page load

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to allow a pop up to display always when a user is basically unregistered and wishes to view the certain page. I saw an example of how to do it but I am completely stuck it's not appearing on my page. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Image: http://puu.sh/cr1Zz/1b5da28635.png

My code  on that page(CSS is listed in the image above)

```
<?php
 session_start();
include ('../includes/config.php'); 
include ('../includes/header.php'); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<title>Honda | </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

<!--start lightbox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.lightbox.css">
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initiate Lightbox
  $(function() {
    $('.gallery1 a').lightbox(); 
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class='modalDialog'>You cannot view this page! Please register</div>

<!--start header-->
<div class="h_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
         <a href="index.php"><img src="../images/logo.png"> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cssmenu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="index.php"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php"><span>About</span></a></li>
       <li class="active" class="has-sub"><a href="service.php"><span>Gallery</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="last"><a href="contact.php"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
     <div class="clear"></div>

                         <div class="search">
                    <h2>search</h2>
            <form>
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter Your search...">
                <input type="submit" value="">
            </form>
        </div>
     <?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    $user=$_POST['user'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];

    $pass = strip_tags($pass); 
$pass = md5($pass); // md5 is used to encrypt your password to make it more secure.



    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'");
    $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($numrows!=0)
    {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $dbusername=$row['username'];
    $dbpassword=$row['password'];
    }

    if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
    {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sess_user']=$user;

    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: member.php");
    }
    } else {
    echo "<div class='results'>Invalid username or password!</div>";
    }

} else {
    echo "All fields are required!";
}
}
?>

                 <div class="search1">

            <h2>login/Register</h2>


            <form action="" method="POST">

            <label>Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="user" required />
            <label>Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="pass" required />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" class="submit" />
                <br><br>
                <center>
                <h2><p><a href="register.php">Register</a></p></h2>
                </center>
    </form> 
    </div>

    </div>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- start content -->
<div class="footer_bg">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="footer2">
        <div class="copy">
            <p class="w3-link">©&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="f_nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Skype</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Linked in</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in your screen shot there is an error, what does the error says?

Comment: @caramba What error are you talking about? The animation?

Comment: ooh, I tought that "1" on the upper-right on the inspector with the `red` "x" has an error ..

Comment: anyway, it's hard to get started with your code. you could set up functions in PHP returning the HTML parts you need at the right places. or you could return classes with PHP to some HTML elements. Then check with javascript (jQuery) if those classes exist. If they are there show or hide elements.

Answer (score 0):

Although you include jQuery, the modal dialog is part of the jQueryUI. But that on its own won't solve your problem. You have declared a div with the class modalDialog, so I suppose this is the line to be shown in the dialog. I would suggest you to use id's instead of classes because a class covers multiple document objects, and you really want to show one dialog here. From the [jQueryUI docs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/):

```
<div id="dialog" title="Please register">
    <p>You cannot view this page! Please register</p>
</div>
```

Add the jQuery call:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

And that should work just fine
If you decide to go with the lightbox modal dialog your code should look like:

```
<div id="test-modal" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
    <h1>lease register</h1>
    <p>You cannot view this page! Please register</p>
    <p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Dismiss</a></p>
</div>
```

To call the code use:

```
  $(function () {
    $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
      type: 'inline',
      preloader: false,
      focus: '#username',
      modal: true
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.magnificPopup.close();
    });
  });
```